# What may cause .ssh/config changes to be ignored

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, openssh

I had a `~/.ssh/config` file that was working fine. it was in this format:

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_null
  TCPKeepAlive no
  ServerAliveCountMax 5000
Host *.domain.com
  User mydomainuser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_domain
Host github.com
  User gcb
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_domain
```

(it had a lot more domains, but lets ignore those for now)

It was working perfectly, even the manual saying that the more specific hosts patterns should be on top, it always worked fine that way. I always ssh'ed to those two domains and the correct identity keys were picked up just fine. I never had a problem were the null key was tried to those two domains. And i used that for years. Always got the right user and key. I've used this same config file on both debian, fedora and osx.

Today, on osx 10.10 (OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011), which worked before, i tried to also add `User unkown` to the `*` rule at the top. and all of a sudden, now every ssh i try, ssh sends user=unkown and identityfile=id_null, which won't log in anywhere. That made me go read the man page for ssh_config and leave everything exactly by the book... and it still won't work. I also tried removing the `User` entry from `*` but that did not fix it.

my current `.ssh/config` file is

```
Host exact.hostname.domain.com
  User mydomainuser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_domain
Host *.domain.com
  User mydomainuser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_domain
Host github.com
  User gcb
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_domain
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_null
  TCPKeepAlive no
  ServerAliveCountMax 50
```

it will still try to use id_null as the identity file when i `ssh exact.hostname.domain.com`. I also tried to use multiple pattern and have `Host *.domain.com exact.hostname.domain.com` instead of repeating. Nothing works. Any ideas what is wrong there?

How can i have a default `User` and `IdentityFile` and override them on a per-domain basis?

---

edit 1:
i added the `Host exact.hostname.domain.com` to both before and after the `*` one. and `ssh -vvv` shows:

```
debug1: /Users/.../.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for exact.hostname.domain.com
debug1: /Users/.../.ssh/config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/.../.ssh/config line 37: Applying options for exact.hostname.domain.com
```

but i still get at the end `no such identity: .ssh/id_null: No such file or directory`

---

edit 2:
some other oddity i saw on `ssh -vvv`

it always tries to use all the keys i have. So i figured because it may have some hardcoded default for `.ssh/id_rsa*`, so i moved all my priv keys to `.ssh/keys/` to hide it from that default, and updated the specific `Host` entries... turn out, it is trying keys from all host entries! even the ones without a match!

recaping, i have one specific host match on top and bottom of file (just to be safe), then hosts that won't match, and the `*` one.

but ssh -vvv shows:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/x/.ssh/keys/id_rsa_git (0x7f954b700530),
debug2: key: /Users/x/.ssh/keys/id_rsa (0x7f954b415700), explicit
debug2: key: /Users/x/.ssh/id_null (0x0), explicit
```

Why on earth it is adding `.ssh/keys/id_rsa_git` if that is the `IdentityFile` only mentioned under `Host github.com`? and why is it ultimately trying to send `id_null` even though it matched the explicit `Host exact.hostname.domain.com` as it says on the debug output `debug1: /Users/.../.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for exact.hostname.domain.com`?

---

edit 3:

after i moved all my keys to `.ssh/keys/*` and only specify the keys in there for each host in `ssh_config`, now i see on every `ssh` instantiation:

`/Users/me/.ssh/id_*[^p][^u][^b]: No such file or directory`

but even after that, it **still** loads the IdentityFiles from **other** hosts in ssh_config while connecting. Why?!

Comment: Have you setup ACLs on `.ssh` and/or the iles inside `.ssh`?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae nope. same as before. checked permissions, they are all fine. .ssh is readable only by me. the priv keys too. the pub ones are readable by me and group

Comment: The ugly truth is that there are precedents for this, see here http://serverfault.com/questions/609334/ssh-is-no-longer-using-ssh-conf something not quite identical but similar, and equally unresolved.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae interesting. i don't think they are __exactly__ the same. mine explicitly says it is loading such lines from my `.ssh/config` file on the debug...

Answer (score 4):

`man ssh-config` says:

> Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.

So make sure that the config you want is in the first matched `Host` entry, as shown by the `ssh -vv`  lines matching: `Applying options for`.

In the general case, this means that `Host *` should be *last*.